# Как передать переменной количество кликов на кнопку JavaScript (без подключения jquery)?

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в программировании, прошу помочь. Надо в переменную передать количество кликов, чтобы дальше эту переменную использовать в следующей функции.
Подсчет делал так:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var count = 0;
  document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className == 'addButton') {
      count++;
    }
  }
};

var step=count;

addPuzzle.addEventListener("click", function(){

for(var j=0; j<=step; j++) {
    
    var quantityQuestion = document.getElementById("newQuestion"+j).value;
    questionsArray.push(quantityQuestion);
    console.log(questionsArray);

};    
puzzleWrapper.innerHTML = '';

build();

addsWrapper.innerHTML = '';

});
```

Comment: Кол-во кликов у вас хранится в `count`, а там где находится `step` `count` не видно. Если вам надо хранить в step, то поднемите её до `window.onload`, и делайте не `count++`, а `step++`, если надо ещё и `count` что бы считался, то вместое `var count=0;`, `count = step`

Comment: Я бы вам предложил сначала найти объект по его классу 'addButton' через метод [.getElementsByClassName("addButton")](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), а уж потом ставить на него [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - это способ зарегистрировать обработчик события, описанный в документации W3C DOM.

Comment: Раз вы учитесь запомните вот это "Чем меньше вызовов тем быстрее выполнение всего кода". А то у вас будет вызываться эта функция при любом нажатии по любому объекту. Вы этот код откуда взяли?

Comment: спасибо, за замечания, подсчет кликов так лучше, но оно все равно не передает его количество в переменную (поправил код,  более расширен, что хочу получить)

Comment: @YuraVelnychuk, отрывок ваш не понятен. Я предполагаю что вы не разбираетесь что значит переменная. `... var step=count; ...` ([var vs let](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)). createQuestionAnswer имя этой переменной на какой объект ссылается? Ваш вопрос был "Отмечен как дубликат", а так бы вам ответил. Советую почитать про Javascript в любой документации от разработчиков браузеров на пример [тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: спасиба за совет